# Affix the table header while the table content is scrolling up-Angular4

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

I want to fix the table header in a fixed position while the content is scrolling up,My .html file is as follows.

```
 <table class="table sticky-header">
                  <thead>
                      <tr class="row-hor-heading">
                          <th colspan="3" scope="row"><span class="bank-name">{{offer.name}}</span> <br /><span class="offers-heading">{{offer.companyname}}</span></th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                      <tr class="row-2-data bg-white">
                          <td colspan="3" scope="row">
                            <button class="btn offerapply-btn waves-effect waves-light" (click)="openThisOffer(offer,leadType)">I&#39;m Interested</button>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                 </tbody>
   </table>
```

In typescript i wrote the code in afterviewInit() function,That is ,

```
 ngAfterViewInit(){


  }
```

i dont know no what to write inside it.Please help me to do that.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting this into your component.ts file

```
public fixed: boolean = false; 
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private doc: Document) {}
     @HostListener("window:scroll", [])
     onWindowScroll() {
        let num = this.document.body.scrollTop;
        if ( num > 50 ) {
        this.fixed = true;
        }else if (this.fixed && num < 5) {
        this.fixed = false;
```

Than you just change table to

```
<table [class.fixed]="fixed" class="table sticky-header">
```

Comment: That is fixing the postion i want to scroll that header also and after certain scroll i want it to be fixed.

Comment: where should i write this in componenets.ts,(afterviewInit or seperately)

Comment: You should put it before your constructor

Comment: document and fixed are showing undefined,how to declare it

Comment: Whoops sorry, forgot to gave you these things. I edited my comment

Comment: @Inject(DOCUMENT) private doc: Document this is showing error,anything to import in the component

Comment: In this case you need to import import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser'; If you ever find yourself having the same problem, please refer to Angular docs, it usually contains the module you have to import.

Comment: sir when i use this each scroll this   onWindowScroll() is triggering.i want it be triggered when i scroll on table.in My DOM many things are there like form ,navbar etc.only table header i want to get fixed after certain scroll omn top.